# Compare 2 columns in python

Tags: python, dataframe

I have a sample dataset like below[image]

Im trying to compare Customer Name with the Quarter and if the customer came in all Quarter I want only those customer written to output file .

In the example the answer should be Customer A & C as they have came across all the quarter.

Can someone help ?

Thanks ,
Meera

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: If you sort the dataframe by "customer name" and then "quarter", it would be trivially easy to scan through the rows one by one and write only those with 4 entries in CY20.